# robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); does not work in alert

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to automate the a authentication window, as I am using Mac I cannot use AutoIT hence i tried using this code

```
driver.get("https://mainsite.com"); //main(parent site)

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); //shifts focus to authentication window

    alert.sendKeys("username"); //fills username in authentication window
    try {

    Robot robot = new Robot();      
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

alert.sendKeys("password"); 

alert.accept();
```

when i execute this code the username gets filled in the alert but the `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);` does not work and the password gets filled in the same username field and hence the alert is not accepted.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried `driver.get("https://username:password@mainsite.com")` already?

Comment: Hi Andersson I have tried driver.get("https://username:password@site.com"); and it works as in when I do alert.accept the sites gets authenticated but the problem with that is the popup/alert does not close after that